# ubuntu 14.04 installation problem

Tags: system-installation

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04. all seem to go well but I cannot play my home videos.
I get a message saying that I need an *Advance Streaming Format Demuxer*
When I click link to get this I am told *could not access repository check internet connection*
The connection seem to be ok as Firebird and mail work fine.
I have reinstalled ubuntu with the same results. I also cannot download from Software center.
I then tried installing mint which payed mp4s ok
I would rather use ubuntu as I have been amazed at the support that is given.

Answer (score 3):

Try executing below command -

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

and do a system restart and check you are able to play the video.

Comment: I get this when I use terminal "E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras"

Comment: Hi really odd.I checked which was the best download server/mirror for me and was advised that non were available check internet connection. I have no problem getting on line or mail.

Comment: Accept the above answer as correct and post a new question: "New Ubuntu install cannot access the Internet"